# Communicating with BizTalk from .NET

Tags: .net, biztalk

We're about to embark on a project where we will be required to communicate with an external Biztalk server via our existing .NET code. My first assumption was that in order to do this we would need to utilize the standard soap adapters offered, however, I've heard that because we are using .NET, there are other more efficient connection techniques available.

Admittedly, my knowledge of Biztalk at present is extremely limited, so I was wondering if somebody could point me at some relevant information?

Thanks
David

Comment: Biztalk can talk using regular SOAP web services - on the .NET side the interface can be implemented either using WCF or traditional ASP.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to send XML messages directly into BizTalk over MSMQ. This is the best and most lightweight solution:

1. Produce the XML messages exactly as you need based on the message schemas
2. Create a simple queue client for enqueing the messages
3. Configure a receive location in BizTalk over the MSMQ adapter to receive the messages

Steps 1 and 2 can be acheived easily using .NET code.

Comment: +1 for suggesting asynchronous before synchronous, as it avoids reliance on both app and BizTalk server being simultaneously available. Note that with asynchronous delivery that compensation may be required with downstream failure, whereas with synchronous communication a 'real time' response is possible.